# Bootstrap - Cols doesnt inherit size of parent

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a problem with bootstrap and css. I need to maked 2x2 panels with 50% width and height of main container. Index looks like:

```
 <Container className="defaultContainer" fluid>
           <Row>
                <Col className="informatsPanel">1</Col>
                <Col className="informatsPanel">2</Col>
                <Col className="informatsPanel">3</Col>
                <Col className="informatsPanel">4</Col>
           </Row>

        </Container>
```

And here CSS

```
.defaultContainer {
margin-top: 1rem;
background-color: #171d2b;
text-align: center;
min-height: 700px;
max-height: 700px;
display: flex;
}

.informatsPanel{
display: inline-block;
border: 2px solid white;
width: 50%;
max-height: 50%;

}
```

Cols doesn't want to get 50% height from defaultContainer. I tried a lot of things and none of them helped.

Comment: just change max-height to height. each panel will pick 50% height of its parent

Comment: I think `min-height` is preferable

Comment: min-width works, but min-height not :/

Comment: Okay the problem was min-height in main container. I set it to height: 700px and now childrens are able to set height in %.